# Largest number of a fixed length in a sequence of digits

Tags: java, algorithm, numbers, array-algorithms

I was solving an algorithmic problem one day that was like:

Given an array of digits, find the largest possible number of fixed length in it ? For ex- "43124911" . Find largest number of length 4? 
Answer would be: 4911

I tried creating O(n) solution for this in java...  Can you help me improve my solution/report bugs/loop-holes/or a Better solution ?? Thanks in advance..

Code:

```
class Solution {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    int arrayOfDigits[] = {4,3,2,4,3,9,1} ;
    boolean newNumber = true ;
    int requiredNumberLength = 4 ;

    int maximumNumber = -1 ;

    int firstDigitOfcurrentNumberNumber = -1 ;
    int lengthOfcurrentNumberNumber = -1 ;
    int currentNumber = -1;
    int futureLargestNumber = -1;
    int futureLargestNumberLength = -1; 

    int currentNumberSub = -1 ;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < arrayOfDigits.length ; i++ ){

        if( newNumber ){
            //System.out.println("In newNumber with " + arrayOfDigits[i] ) ;
            currentNumber = arrayOfDigits[i] ;
            lengthOfcurrentNumberNumber = 1 ;
            firstDigitOfcurrentNumberNumber = currentNumber ;
            newNumber = false ;

            if( isFeasible(i,arrayOfDigits.length ,requiredNumberLength ) )
                continue ;
            else
                break ;
        }
        currentNumber = nextNum( currentNumber , arrayOfDigits[i] ) ;
        futureLargestNumber = arrayOfDigits[i] ;

        if( !isFeasible(i,arrayOfDigits.length,requiredNumberLength) ){
            futureLargestNumber = -1 ;
        }   

        if( firstDigitOfcurrentNumberNumber > futureLargestNumber ){
            lengthOfcurrentNumberNumber++ ;
            if( lengthOfcurrentNumberNumber == requiredNumberLength ){
                newNumber = true ;
                if( currentNumber > maximumNumber ){
                    maximumNumber = currentNumber ;
                }
            }
            continue ;
        }
        //System.out.println(futureLargestNumber);
        if( futureLargestNumber > firstDigitOfcurrentNumberNumber ){
            newNumber = true ;
            i-- ;
            continue ;
        }

        //firstDigitOfcurrentNumberNumber == futureLargestNumber
        lengthOfcurrentNumberNumber++ ;
        futureLargestNumberLength = 1 ;

        if( lengthOfcurrentNumberNumber == requiredNumberLength ){
            if( currentNumber > maximumNumber ){
                maximumNumber = currentNumber ;
            }
            currentNumber = futureLargestNumber ;
            lengthOfcurrentNumberNumber = futureLargestNumberLength ;
            continue;
        }
        for( int j = i+1 ; j < arrayOfDigits.length ; j++ ){

            futureLargestNumberLength++ ;
            futureLargestNumber = nextNum(futureLargestNumber,arrayOfDigits[j]) ;
            lengthOfcurrentNumberNumber++ ;
            currentNumber = nextNum(currentNumber,arrayOfDigits[j]) ;

            if( lengthOfcurrentNumberNumber == requiredNumberLength ){
                if( currentNumber > maximumNumber ){
                    maximumNumber = currentNumber ;
                }
                currentNumber = futureLargestNumber ;
                lengthOfcurrentNumberNumber = futureLargestNumberLength ;
                i = j ;
                break ;
            }

            currentNumberSub = calculateSub( currentNumber , lengthOfcurrentNumberNumber , futureLargestNumberLength ) ;

            if( currentNumberSub > futureLargestNumber ){
                i = j ;
                break ;
            }
            if( futureLargestNumber > currentNumberSub ){
                currentNumber = futureLargestNumber ;
                lengthOfcurrentNumberNumber = futureLargestNumberLength ;
                i = j ;
                break ;
            }
        }   

    }

    System.out.println( maximumNumber ) ;
}
public static boolean isFeasible( int i , int arrayOfDigitslengthOfcurrentNumberNumbergth , int requiredNumberLength ){
    if( i-1+requiredNumberLength < arrayOfDigitslengthOfcurrentNumberNumbergth ){
        return true ;
    }else{ 
        return false ;
    }
}
public static int nextNum( int currentNumber , int digit ){
    return (10*currentNumber)+digit ;
}
public static int calculateSub( int currentNumber , int lengthOfcurrentNumberNumber , int futureLargestNumberLength ){
    return (int)(currentNumber/Math.pow(10,lengthOfcurrentNumberNumber-futureLargestNumberLength));
}
}
```

Comment: So, you're looking for code review? There is a dedicated stackexchange page for that (codereview.stackexchange.com). You should ask there.

Comment: Note that code that doesn't work as expected is off-topic on Code Review - we *may* find bugs or issues, but your code must, to the best of your knowledge, work exactly as intended. In other words, CR will not change *what* your code does, only *how* it does it.

Comment: Is 'fixed length' limited?

Comment: Yes. Fixed length is limited

Comment: @Tom ! Review it once https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85927/to-find-the-largest-number-of-fixed-length-with-an-array

Answer (score 1):

Simple and straightforward O(n) algorithm - just iterate through all len-digits numbers, formed from sequential array elements

```
Len = 4
Arr = [4,3,1,2,4,9,1,1]
N = Arr.Length
Max = Arr[0]
PowerTen = 1;
for i = 1 to Len - 1
      Max = Max * 10 + Arr[i]
      PowerTen = PowerTen * 10
//Now Max = 4312, PowerTen = 1000

Current = Max
for i = 0 to N - Len - 1 
      //construct next Len-digit number
      Current = (Current - Arr[i] * PowerTen) * 10 + Arr[i + Len]
      //4312 - 4000 = 312;  312 * 10 = 3120; 3120 + 4 = 3124
      if Max < Current
             Max = Current
```

Comment: I like it that you used pseudo code; that gives an explanation without giving the full solution.